# Efficient partial string search on large pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-emr

Hello fellow developers,

I'm currently working on a PySpark project where I need to perform a join between two large dataframes. One dataframe contains around 10 million entries with short strings as keywords(2-5 words), while the other dataframe holds 30 million records with variations(5-10 word strings), merchants, and counts.

The goal is to join the dataframes based on the condition that the keywords in the first one are contained within the variations of the second dataframe. However, the current code is running for over 3 hours on a large EMR cluster and still hasn't finished.

**EMR configuration**

5 task nodes: m5.16xlarge (32cores/256GB per node)
Master node: m5.8xlarge (4cores/64GB)

**spark-submit command:**

time spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1   --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.0  --num-executors 30 --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=6g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=6g --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 42g --driver-memory g 42 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=409 join_code.py

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
# Code for join
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DataFrameJoin").getOrCreate()

# Loading dataframes
keywords_df = spark.read.parquet("keywords.parquet")
variations_df= spark.read.parquet("variations.parquet")

# Cross-joining based on keyword containment
result = keywords_df.join(variations_df,F.col(variations).contains(F.col(keyword)),how='left')
result.show()
```

Comment: hmm.. this might need a creative solution. does variations have any patterns ( does the variation always start with the keyword or is the keyword always after a specific word?). OR maybe is there a date column you could add to your join or filter the data on?

Comment: No, there's nothing else I have in the table to do a match on.

Comment: I hope you are partitioning the dataframes in suitable number of partitions. Another thing you can do is convert the keywords into unique numbers in both the tables and then do contain operation. String comparison is expensive as compared interger comparison.

Comment: Thank you, I am doing that. I considered the mapping from k/ws to unique numbers. I am not quite sure how to do this, when we need to do "contains" kind of a substring match

Comment: Thanks for mentioning partition here - I checked the partitions. My large dataframe of 30M rows(500MB) was getting partitioned into 50 only. I repartitioned it into 3000, speed has gone up. Smaller dataframe(10M rows, and  is partitioned into 2 by default, which I understood that is not right. I did some trial-errors with partition numbers. Used ganglia and spark UI, takes 40 mins now.

Comment: In the first pass, get unique string values which you need to match in both columns, do some analysis on the values on how many uniques you have. Then you can use this answer to map. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577758/pyspark-dataframe-map-strings-to-numerics

Comment: Another speedup optimization you can do is to do broadcast join. Broadcast the smaller dataframe into the bigger one while doing the join. Look up Broadcast Join to figure it out.

Comment: Your datasize seems to be very small. If you optimize is properly. This task should take about <10 minutes. I have optimized datasizes of 1B rows and it took about 5 minutes to finish on similar cluster sizes.

Comment: Thank you, looks like the resource optimization is bad!

Comment: I can see that my cluster CPU capacity is only 45% used, that could be one problem. Similarly, memory is also very underutilized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255065/discussion-between-pnv-and-user238607).

Comment: I thought of one more optimization which can speed up things by a lot. If you look at values `("type green pstr")` in variations dataframe, it is repeated three times. Similarly in keywords dataframe `("greenpstr")` could be repeated. I would suggest to extract out the Uniques from both the dataframes, do fuzzy matching over the uniques and then join back the result with the original dataframes. This should speed up the code by a lot. There is no point in calling `fuzzy match function` redundantly.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I did that as well.

Comment: Did materializing the dataframes with `count() and show()` help with speedups? It always helped me. Also it helps to cache a particular dataframe if you are using its results multiple in future transformations.

Answer (score 1):

If Fuzzy matching is taking lot of your time, then following solution could help. It uses rapidfuzz library which is highly optimized so should run faster. There are mutiple ratio options to choose from. Take a look at this github page and test which ratio suits your needs the best.

https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import rapidfuzz

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

keyword_given = [
    ["green pstr",],
    ["greenpstr",],
    ["wlmrt", ],
    ["walmart",],
    ["walmart super",]
    ]

keywordColumns = ["keyword"]
keyword_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=keyword_given, schema = keywordColumns)

print("keyword_df dataframe")
keyword_df.show(truncate=False)


variations = [
            ("type green pstr", "ABC", 100),
            ("type green pstr","PQR",200),
            ("type green pstr", "NZSD", 2999),
            ("wlmrt payment","walmart",200),
            ("wlmrt solutions", "walmart", 200),
            ("nppssdwlmrt", "walmart", 2000)
             ]

variationsColumns = ["variations", "entity", "ID"]
variations_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=variations, schema = variationsColumns)

print("variations_df dataframe")
variations_df.show(truncate=False)

def evalutate_helper_spark(keyw, var):
    return rapidfuzz.fuzz.partial_ratio(keyw, var)


calculate_ratio = udf(lambda keyw, var : evalutate_helper_spark(keyw, var))

middle_df = variations_df.crossJoin(keyword_df)

middle_df = middle_df.withColumn("partial_ratio", calculate_ratio(F.col("keyword"), F.col("variations")))


print("middle df show")
middle_df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Here's the output :

```
keyword_df dataframe
+-------------+
|keyword      |
+-------------+
|green pstr   |
|greenpstr    |
|wlmrt        |
|walmart      |
|walmart super|
+-------------+

variations_df dataframe
+---------------+-------+----+
|variations     |entity |ID  |
+---------------+-------+----+
|type green pstr|ABC    |100 |
|type green pstr|PQR    |200 |
|type green pstr|NZSD   |2999|
|wlmrt payment  |walmart|200 |
|wlmrt solutions|walmart|200 |
|nppssdwlmrt    |walmart|2000|
+---------------+-------+----+

middle df show
+---------------+-------+----+-------------+------------------+
|variations     |entity |ID  |keyword      |partial_ratio     |
+---------------+-------+----+-------------+------------------+
|type green pstr|ABC    |100 |green pstr   |100.0             |
|type green pstr|ABC    |100 |greenpstr    |88.88888888888889 |
|type green pstr|ABC    |100 |wlmrt        |33.333333333333336|
|type green pstr|ABC    |100 |walmart      |25.0              |
|type green pstr|ABC    |100 |walmart super|40.0              |
|type green pstr|PQR    |200 |green pstr   |100.0             |
|type green pstr|PQR    |200 |greenpstr    |88.88888888888889 |
|type green pstr|PQR    |200 |wlmrt        |33.333333333333336|
|type green pstr|PQR    |200 |walmart      |25.0              |
|type green pstr|PQR    |200 |walmart super|40.0              |
|type green pstr|NZSD   |2999|green pstr   |100.0             |
|type green pstr|NZSD   |2999|greenpstr    |88.88888888888889 |
|type green pstr|NZSD   |2999|wlmrt        |33.333333333333336|
|type green pstr|NZSD   |2999|walmart      |25.0              |
|type green pstr|NZSD   |2999|walmart super|40.0              |
|wlmrt payment  |walmart|200 |green pstr   |46.15384615384615 |
|wlmrt payment  |walmart|200 |greenpstr    |50.0              |
|wlmrt payment  |walmart|200 |wlmrt        |100.0             |
|wlmrt payment  |walmart|200 |walmart      |83.33333333333334 |
|wlmrt payment  |walmart|200 |walmart super|70.0              |
|wlmrt solutions|walmart|200 |green pstr   |40.0              |
|wlmrt solutions|walmart|200 |greenpstr    |36.36363636363637 |
|wlmrt solutions|walmart|200 |wlmrt        |100.0             |
|wlmrt solutions|walmart|200 |walmart      |83.33333333333334 |
|wlmrt solutions|walmart|200 |walmart super|70.0              |
|nppssdwlmrt    |walmart|2000|green pstr   |42.85714285714286 |
|nppssdwlmrt    |walmart|2000|greenpstr    |46.15384615384615 |
|nppssdwlmrt    |walmart|2000|wlmrt        |100.0             |
|nppssdwlmrt    |walmart|2000|walmart      |83.33333333333334 |
|nppssdwlmrt    |walmart|2000|walmart super|55.55555555555556 |
+---------------+-------+----+-------------+------------------+
```